# Python, Evaluate a Variable value as a Variable

Tags: python

I'd like to do something like below: particularly the 'f.eval(field)' part, such that it evaluates the value of the variable as the field name.  How does one accomplish this in Python?

```
def punctuated_object_list(objects, field):
    field_list = [f.eval(field) for f in objects]
    if len(field_list) > 0:
        if len(field_list) == 1:
            return field_list[0]
        else:
            return ', '.join(field_list[:-1]) + ' & ' + field_list[-1]
    else:
        return u''
```

Comment: +1 with my thanks for asking this question before I needed to :) .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`getattr(f, field)`, if I understand you correctly (that is, if you might have `field = "foo"`, and want `f.foo`). If not, you might want to clarify. Python has an `eval()`, and I don't know what other languages' `eval()` you want the equivalent of.

Comment: +1 beat me by seconds :-) Bonus doc: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr

Comment: Silly me... eval(eval()) in python... thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 4):

```
getattr( object, 'field' ) #note that field is a string

f = 'field_name'
#...
getattr( object, f )


#to get a list of fields in an object, you can use dir()
dir( object )
```

For more details, see: http://www.diveintopython.org/power_of_introspection/index.html

**Don't use eval**, even if the strings are safe in this particular case! Just don't get yourself used to it. If you're getting the string from the user it could be malicious code.

Murphy's law: if things can go wrong, they will.

Comment: Who would insert the "malicious" code?  Python is distributed as source.  Why mess around trying to get eval to break when the code is available to change?  eval is no less safe than all the rest of Python.

Answer (score 1):

The python equivalent of `eval()` is `eval()`

```
x = 9
eval("x*2")
```

will give you 18.

```
v = "x"
eval(v+"*2")
```

works too.

Comment: eval is evil! better not use it at all, there's always a better way

Answer (score 0):

To get at a list of all the fields in a Python object you can access its `__dict__` property.

```
class Testing():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Joe"
        self.age = 30

test = Testing()
print test.__dict__
```

results:

```
{'age': 30, 'name': 'Joe'}
```

Comment: Not the same. The object might not even have such an easily accessible __dict__ (might have to do something like object.__getattribute__(foo, '__dict__') if the object is mean), and it might have a new __getattr__.